# how to save d3js charts and use that charts later

Tags: d3.js

I am creating one application where a end user create a chart with a simple Gui and charts are d3.js also user can save that and edit it whenever required in near future.
so how do i save that chart or in which format, so that in future a end user can edit that chart.

Comment: D3 is data driven, as the name suggests, so you might want to save the data model, which must be maintained while the user creates the chart. This way you just need to save the array as JSON string, which is easy to store for later use.

Comment: Thanks @Imperative but is it possible to export complete data into xml so that a end user can make necessary changes which they want.